# Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' in s3sync Plugin of Serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I had installed the plugin by following command in serverless 2.53.1.

```
npm install --save-dev serverless-s3-sync
```

After installing I had imported the plugin like this in serverless.yml

```
plugins:
    - serverless-plugin-common-excludes
    - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
    - serverless-python-requirements 
    - serverless-s3-sync
```

But (serverless deploy) is giving the following error. Screenshot of error is also attached. (This error only happens when I import this plugin of serverless-s3-sync in serverless.yml file other plugins are running fine).

**ERROR DETAILS:**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' of undefined
> at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:291:24)
> at WriteStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
> at NodejsStreamOutputAdapter.ondata (C:\serverless_v2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:619:20) at NodejsStreamOutputAdapter.emit (node:events:394:28)

Here's a full error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After a *lot* of digging, I isolated the cause to having multiple incompatible versions of `graceful-fs` in the resolved node sub-dependencies.

In my case I'm using the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin, not `serverless-s3-sync`, but the error is the same.  Both plugins list `graceful-fs` as a dependency.

You can see from `yarn list` that there are three different versions of `graceful-fs` installed:

```
% yarn list

├─ fs-extra@9.1.0
│  ├─ at-least-node@^1.0.0
│  ├─ graceful-fs@^4.2.0 ← version used by fs-extra
│  ├─ jsonfile@^6.0.1
│  └─ universalify@^2.0.0
…
├─ graceful-fs@4.2.2 ← version directly declared in package.json
…
├─ jsonfile@6.1.0
│  ├─ graceful-fs@^4.1.6
│  ├─ graceful-fs@4.1.15 ← version used by jsonfile
│  └─ universalify@^2.0.0
…
```

It seems that the stream objects created by one version of this library are not consumable by the other version.

With `yarn` I solved this by pinning `graceful-fs` to the latest version by adding this to my `package.json` file:

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "**/graceful-fs": "4.2.8"
  }
```

For `npm` it should be possible to achieve the same thing using [npm-force-resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions), but it appears the syntax is slightly different (I have not tested this):

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.8"
  }
```

Removing the lock file and `node_modules` folder and reinstalling might solve the problem, but given the pain this has caused, I was happier to pin the version in `package.json`.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for sharing this!

Comment: @MattRabe it took a silly amount of time to figure out the cause of this issue.  Glad to know it helped someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message twice from Serverless Framework. The error message is not descriptive for the root cause. The way I could resolve it was:

- Delete the two directories named (1) node_modules and  (2) .serverless
- Reinstall the dependencies using serverless instead of npm e.g. `serverless plugin install -n serverless-s3-sync`

Now I could deploy the project again. But the error message is misleading and should be considered an error in itself that the error message is a source of painful confusion.